# Bash suggestions on command?

Tags: bash, function

I am dyslexic and as such find it hard to spell. I am looking for a bash script/function that takes an input and checks it against a given list for similar phrases. e.g. in psudocode:

```
List=['Bernoulli\'s Function', 'Bernoulli\'s Equation',  'Convolution', 'Gamow Argument']
foo_function(List, 'Bernoli')
Output -> 'Bernoulli\'s Function','Bernoulli\'s Equation'
```

Does such a function exist in bash?

Comment: are your sure that it's called as  `foo_function(List, 'Bernoli')` but not as `foo_function(List, 'Bernoulli')` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest ye that is my point (sorry if I didn't make it clear). I am wanting it to suggest phrases that are similar (but not necessarily identical) to what I typed (like a spell-checker).

Comment: bash is not that tool to find similarities between words. Besides, **what is the minimum similarity ratio**?

Comment: Sorry, I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323977/string-similarity-score-hash answers my question of at least a method of doing this.

Comment: I can suggest a short solution, but only if you answered my previous question (about ratio)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Sorry I am not exactly sure what a similarity ratio is (well at least not enough to put a quantitative value on a minimum). If you could give a reasonable marker that would be great.

Comment: so are this words `'Bernoli'` and `Libero` should be treated as similar in your case?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest preferably not, I think there should be some ordering dependence.

Comment: so you should describe such dependence (Let's say the first 3 chars should be identical or somehow else)